# Track after hour users on computer

Tags: windows-8, logging

If I wanted to track all users that log-in to a specific computer, regardless of admin rights or not, what would be the best, most efficient, least obvious method of doing so? And without snooping on specifics is it possible to see what applications are run during these sessions?

Software? Batch file? Etc.?

System: Win8 on Active Directory

Comment: First off, what operating system are you using, Windows 7, Windows 8.1, or Windows 10?

Comment: Yeah, facepalm. Added relevant information.

Comment: [You can't, .....](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericfitz/archive/2008/08/20/tracking-user-logon-activity-using-logon-events.aspx), or at least not reliably.  You can log just about any event you want, you just have to enable it, you obviously can't track something that wasn't logged.

Comment: Got it. That's less than optimal. I was hoping for a batch file that would track login name and time or something similar... ah well.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows Professional, you can enable login auditing in the Group Policy Editor.  To open it, run `gpedit.msc`, then look under:

> Computer Configuration → Windows Settings → Security Settings → Local
>   Policies → Audit Policy.

There are options to log both successful and failed login attempts.

You can later review the logs in the Event Viewer under Windows Logs → Security.